# Alamofire Network Activity Indicator not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to use AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator (v2.2) and Alamofire (v4.5) but I cant manage to make it work
I have a Singleton in which I execute the requests.

This is an example of a request coming from my Singleton class:

```
     Alamofire.request(Constants.getTimeline, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseData() { response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(data: value)
                callback(json)
            case .failure(_):
                callback(nil)
            }
        }
```

And I initialize the AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator in `AppDelegate.swift` in the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
`NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.isEnabled = true        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.startDelay = 0        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.completionDelay = 10`

competionDelay I've try to set to any value but still nothing helps. What can be the problem in order the network indicator to be shown in the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it's coming on status, try to change completionDelay time 10.0 to 2.0 seconds and check!